# Dynamically create select box in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json, jquery-ui

I am working on wijmo grid and I want to add selection box inside the grid whos data is coming form JSON.

Here are my code which I tried but its not showing the option data inside box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({ 
    url: "DeviceType",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType : "application/json",
    success: function (responce) { 
        if (responce.listResponse.items.length > 0) {
            $.each(responce.listResponse.items, function (i, entity) {                   
                $('#devicetype').append(
                    $('<select/>', {
                        'id': 'deviceType' + entity.paramCode,
                        'type': 'select', 
                        'name':         'deviceType', 
                        'value': entity.paramValue
                    }),
                    $('<options />', {
                        'for': 'deviceType' + entity.paramValue, 
                        'text':         entity.paramValue
                        }).click(function() {
                        alert(entity.paramCode);
                    })  
                    );                  
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
<body>  
<div id="devicetype" name="deviceType" ></div>
</body>
```

Comment: did you try `<option />` instead of `<options />`?

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the options to the `#devicetype`, but you need to append them to the select:

```
/* not tested */
$( '#devicetype' ).append(
    $( '<select/>', {
        'id': 'deviceType' + entity.paramCode,
        'type': 'select',
        'name': 'deviceType',
        'value': entity.paramValue
    } ).append(
        $( '<option />', {
            'for': 'deviceType' + entity.paramValue,
            'text': entity.paramValue
        } )
    ).click( function() {
        alert( entity.paramCode );
    } )
);
```

**UPDATE**: Oh – and as tpaksu stated in the comment above, you have misspelled `option`.
Maybe you should compile all the options first in a separate loop – the current version only works for one option.

Comment: :Its working fine....but there is one more problem...It is showing too many selection box but I want only one and the Param value should show inside and when select paramCode will select....please help!!

Comment: As I said in the update: you wont create the select in a loop, but the option tags; store them into a variable and append them to a single select.

Comment: I have tried the code but its still giving the same output...can you please give me the code..? Thanks Tina!!